# Scrapy: response.xpath prints None, but upon clicking into weblink, xPath is correct

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to print out the h1 title of the item that I am trying to scrape. I have tried printing the result of
`print(response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/h1').get())` from a product like this https://www.steinersports.com/football/tampa-bay-buccaneers/tom-brady-tampa-bay-buccaneers-super-bowl-lv-champions-autographed-white-nike-game-jersey-with-lv-mvp-inscription/o-8094+t-92602789+p-2679909745+z-8-2492872768?_ref=p-FALP:m-GRID:i-r20c0:po-60.

I am not sure how to go about debugging this error, since when I click into the links that are returning none and check the xpath, it is correct. Any help is appreciated, full code below:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request


class SteinerSportsCrawlSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'steinersports_crawl_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['steinersports.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.steinersports.com/football/signed/o-1383+fa-56+z-95296299-3058648695?_ref=m-TOPNAV',
        ]
    base_url = 'https://www.steinersports.com/football/signed/o-1383+fa-56+z-95296299-3058648695?_ref=m-TOPNAV'



    rules = (

        
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/signed'), follow=True), 
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'football/', deny=r'/signed'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = {}
        description_flag = True
        price_flag = True
        item_description = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[17]/div/div[2]/div').get()
        print(item)
        #item_price = response.xpath('//span[@class="product__price"]/text()').get()
        
        print(response.xpath('html/body/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/h1').get())
        item['item_name'] = response.xpath('html/body/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/h1').get()
        
        
        return item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly access the `h1` tag using the `data-talos` attribute. This xpath should get the title:

```
response.xpath("//h1[@data-talos='labelPdpProductTitle']/text()").extract_first()
```